# weird behaviour of NVL(<Column_name>,Sequence.nextval) when the colummn has data?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql, sequence

I've created a sequence like this :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test2
  MINVALUE 0
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  START WITH 0
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Both of these two queries show me the number 0:

```
 select SEQ_TEST2.nextval from DUAL;   
 select SEQ_TEST2.currval from DUAL;
```

And I have a table as you can see here :

```
create table STUDENT
(
  st_id      NUMBER,
  first_name VARCHAR2(150),
  last_name  VARCHAR2(150)
)
```

After executing the query below ,

```
select t.st_id , nvl(t.st_id , seq_test2.nextval) as seq
from STUDENT t
```

When there is no null in `st_id` column , the result I get is this :

```
    st_id    seq
   ---------------
      1       1
      2       2
      3       3
      4       4
      5       5
```

when I insert a row for which the column `st_id` is null , after executing the query above the result is like below :

```
      st_id    seq
   ---------------
       1       1
       2       2
       3       3
       4       4
       5       5
       null    10
```

And if I execute it again I see:

```
      st_id    seq
   ---------------
       1       1
       2       2
       3       3
       4       4
       5       5
       null    16
```

Seems like even if column `st_id` has data , this part of the `NVL function` (seq_test2.nextval)
gets executed !!!! Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `NVL` does not short-circuit, so even when the first input is not null the second argument is evaluated.
>
> `COALESCE` does use short-circuit evaluation

True, but that's not the reason for the behaviour Pantea has described here. References to `NEXTVAL` and `CURRVAL` are not functions but [pseudocolumns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm#i1009336). No matter if you use `nvl` or `coalesce` (or `case` or `decode`), `sequence.nextval` will always be evaluated for every fetched row and the sequence value will grow.

Answer (score 3):

`NVL` does not short-circuit, so even when the first input is not null the second argument is evaluated.

`COALESCE` does use [short-circuit evaluation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COALESCE.html#GUID-3F9007A7-C0CA-4707-9CBA-1DBF2CDE0C87).

--edit
But that doesn't matter, see the answer from Andi Schloegl